# How can I increase the amount of VRAM for my Windows 10 VM in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, memory, graphics-card, virtual-machine

My system specs:

> Windows 10 32-bit, and I have a 64-bit version.
>
> 3gb of RAM
>
> Nvidia GeForce 9600M GT (Total Graphics Memory: 2046 MB, Dedicated
>   Video Memory: 512 MB,  Shared System Memory: 1534 MB)
>
> Intel Core 2 Duo P8400 @2.26 Ghz (Support for Virtualization)

My virtual machine's specs:

> 2048 MB of RAM
>
> 2 CPU cores
>
> 256 MB of VRAM (3D & 2D Acceleration Enabled)
>
> Paravirtualization interface is set to default

**If you need anymore information just ask**

So, my problem is the VM is just awfully slow, takes a lot of time to boot, more than my old PC which had almost the same specs than the VM's. It's just too slow and I need help with it.

Comment: Why would more VRAM (you probably have plenty allocated) help it to boot faster? http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I am not talking about boot speed, I know that i should add more ram if I wanted it to boot faster, I just want it to not be so painfully slow when I'm using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtualbox only supports 256 MB of VRAM, however, the virtual GPU the VM is using is one of many emulated by Virtualbox and has nothing to do with the VRAM of you physical GPU.

Also, the amount of VRAM is probably not the problem of the machine being slow.
One problem is probably the amount of RAM in your machine. Not only will the 1 GB left for you physical computer be problematic but also the 2GB of ram for the VM will be problematic. As soon as windows runs low on system memory, it will start using virtual memory, which results in a slow responding Windows OS especially if you are using an old HDD.

The Intel Core 2 Duo P8400 is also not really made for virtualization, I would recommend having at least a CPU with 4 cores to do anything meaningful with virtualization.

I'm guessing you are trying to run a 64-bit application in the VM because your host system is 32 bit? In this case, it would probably best to reinstall Windows 10 64 bit on your hardware, no new license is required to do that.

Comment: No, I don't want to run a 64-bit application because as you can see in my question up there, I added that it is a 32-bit OS

Comment: I actually already have a 64-bit OS, not in a VM.

Comment: Well the only way I could see Windows 32 bit running fluidly would be by installing it in parallel to the 64 bit version of Windows 10. The question is do you really need Windows 10 32 bit or this an xy problem http://xyproblem.info/